# append td row in datatable Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, dynamic-data, bootstrap-selectpicker

This question already asked but that is not solving my issue.

In my project am adding table row dynamically. While appending a new row I got this error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).selectpicker is not a function` please check below screenshot.

[image]

**HTML code:**

```
<button type="button" id="addprocessplaningList" data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add process List" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button>
```

**my js code:**

```
$('document').ready(function() {

    var process_row = "<?= count($productProcessPlanData['processData']) + 1?>";
    //var process_row_count = "<?= count($productProcessPlanData['processData']) + 1?>";
    $('#addprocessplaningList').click(function() {

        var html = '';
        html += '<tr id="processPlaningList' + process_row + '">';
        html += '<td></td>';

        html += `
              <td>
              <select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true"name="processPlaningList[` + process_row + `][processId]" id="processId[` + process_row + `]" placeholder="This is a search placeholder" required>
                  <option value="">Type Process Name</option>
                   <?php foreach($processLists as $process){ ?>
                   <option value="<?=$process['processId']?>"><?=$process['processName']?></option>
                   <?php } ?>
                </select>
              </td>
            `;
        html += `
            <td>
              <input class="form-control" name="processPlaningList[` + process_row + `][drawingNo]" id="drawingNo[` + process_row + `]" placeholder="Enter Drawing No" required>
            </td>
            `;
        html += `
              <td style="position:relative">
                <input class="form-control flatpickr-input datepicker-timepicker" type="text" name="processPlaningList[` + process_row + `][cycleTime]" id="cycleTime_` + process_row + `" required style="border: 1px solid #ccc;">
              </td>
            `;

        html += '<td><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#processPlaningList' + process_row + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_remove }}" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
        html += '</tr>';

        $('.dtProcessPlan tbody').append(html)
        process_row++;

        // call selectpicker
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
    });
});
<!-- auto compelete -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
</script>
<!-- auto compelete -->
```

> please help me to solve this `error`

Comment: I tried your code but I can't replicate the issue: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-de68nv)

Comment: @lbsn: Thanks for your answer your code is working but am having issue